# How to plot pairwise distances of two-dimensional vectors?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have a set of data in python likes:

```
x y angle
```

If I want to calculate the distance between two points with all possible value and plot the distances with the difference between two angles.

```
x, y, a = np.loadtxt('w51e2-pa-2pk.log', unpack=True)
n = 0
f=(((x[n])-x[n+1:])**2+((y[n])-y[n+1:])**2)**0.5
d = a[n]-a[n+1:]
plt.scatter(f,d)
```

There are 255 points in my data.

`f` is the distance and `d` is the difference between two angles.
My question is can I set `n = [1,2,3,.....255]` and do the calculation again to get the `f` and `d` of all possible pairs?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want a way to calculate the 255x255 different possibilities to calculate the distances/angles between each point (maybe except for the actual point itself)?

Comment: Yes! But is (255x255)/2 different possibilities .

Comment: Yes you are right ...

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the pairwise distances through [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) by considering it as an outer operation on the array of 2-dimensional vectors as follows:

```
vecs = np.stack((x, y)).T
np.linalg.norm(vecs[np.newaxis, :] - vecs[:, np.newaxis], axis=2)
```

For example,

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
   ...: y = np.array([3, 4, 6])
   ...: vecs = np.stack((x, y)).T
   ...: np.linalg.norm(vecs[np.newaxis, :] - vecs[:, np.newaxis], axis=2)
   ...: 
Out[1]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  1.41421356,  3.60555128],
       [ 1.41421356,  0.        ,  2.23606798],
       [ 3.60555128,  2.23606798,  0.        ]])
```

Here, the (*i*, *j*)'th entry is the distance between the *i*'th and *j*'th vectors.

The case of the pairwise differences between angles is similar, but simpler, as you only have one dimension to deal with:

```
In [2]: a = np.array([10, 12, 15])
   ...: a[np.newaxis, :] - a[: , np.newaxis]
   ...: 
Out[2]: 
array([[ 0,  2,  5],
       [-2,  0,  3],
       [-5, -3,  0]])
```

Moreover, `plt.scatter` does not care that the results are given as matrices, and putting everything together using the notation of the question, you can obtain the plot of angles by distances by doing something like

```
vecs = np.stack((x, y)).T
f = np.linalg.norm(vecs[np.newaxis, :] - vecs[:, np.newaxis], axis=2)
d = angle[np.newaxis, :] - angle[: , np.newaxis]
plt.scatter(f, d)
```

Comment: It doesn't work! It shows ''ValueError: x and y must be the same size'',but I'm pretty sure x and y are in the same length.

Comment: In the scatter plot, I expect that there will be (255*255)/2 points but it turns out that there are 255*255 points. I guess it is because I count the same two points twice. (x-x')^2+(y-y')^2 goes to (A-A')and (x'-x)^2+(y'-y)^2 goes to (A'-A) . But they should be counted only once. How could I fixed it?

Comment: That depends entirely on the problem you want to solve. Perhaps you actually want something like |A - A'|? If so, put in an `np.abs` in the definition of `d`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a for loop and `range()` to iterate over n, e.g. like like this:

```
n = len(x)

for i in range(n):
    # do something with the current index
    # e.g. print the points 
    print x[i]
    print y[i]
```

But note that if you use `i+1` inside the last iteration, this will already be outside of your list.

Also in your calculation there are errors. `(x[n])-x[n+1:]` does not work because `x[n]` is a single value in your list while `x[n+1:]` is a list starting from `n+1`'th element. You can not subtract a list from an int or whatever it is.

Maybe you will have to even use two nested loops to do what you want. I guess that you want to calculate the distance between each point so a two dimensional array may be the data structure you want.

Comment: You don't actually need any explicit loops; as we are dealing with `numpy` arrays, the operation can be vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in all combinations of the points in `x` and `y` I suggest to use `itertools`, which will give you all possible combinations. Then you can do it like follows:

```
import itertools

f = [((x[i]-x[j])**2 + (y[i]-y[j])**2)**0.5 for i,j in  itertools.product(255,255) if i!=j]
# and similar for the angles
```

But maybe there is even an easier way...

Comment: It doesn't work.. It shows"TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" . Have no idea with this...